# How modulus works with negative numbers in R?

Tags: r, modulus

How modulus works with negative integers in R:

```
-90 %% 360
90 %% -360
-400 %% 360
400 %% -360
```

outputs:

```
270
-270
320
-320
```

what is the rationale behind this?

The answer from @JimSlonder:

```
a <- c(-90,90,-400,400)
b <- c(360,-360,360,-360)

modulus <- function(a,b)
  a-floor(a/b)*b


all("%%"(a,b) == modulus(a,b))
```

Comment: It doesn't explain the effect of negatives? could you explain it to me!?!

Comment: `a%%b==a-floor(a/b)*b` so e.g.  `-90-floor(-90/360)*360 == 270`